# Nuxt.js | watching route changes on component

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I am pushing route parameter/query changes from a component, and I want to watch changes from another component. I was handling the issue by using below syntax on `vue`

```js
watch: {
    "$route.params.index": function (val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
}
```

What is the corresponding syntax in nuxt ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this one works with Vue, it should totally work with Nuxt too. Do you have an error somewhere?

Comment: No error, it is just not listening

Comment: And `vue-router` is not actually truly compatible with `nuxt` I had to change from `this.$router.push` to  `this.$nuxt.$options.router.push`

Comment: Try to debug by listening to `$route` at first. Also, I'd like to have a [repro] to see where `this.$router.push` is not working because it totally should. Nuxt uses `vue-router` behind the curtains.